# Does the image upload have more restrictive requirements?

Tags: support, images

I right tried to upload an image to use in a post, but it was not accepted because the following error:

> Failed to upload image; the format is not supported

The image was a JPEG; I also tried with a PNG image, but I got the same error. I then noticed the URL started with https://, tried with http:// but I got the same result.
The only way I had to add the picture was to take a screenshot of it, and then add it to the post.

Are there other restrictions that are applied? This is the first time I have such an error.

This is the image I am trying to include: http://drupal.org/files/project-images/path_breadcrumbs_settings_page.png.

I have tried with Firefox 21 and Safari 6.0.5 (8536.30.1) running on OS X 10.8.4, but the result doesn't change.

Comment: related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/184641/unable-to-upload-a-png-to-include-in-a-post-from-local-computer

Comment: Can you let me know what mime-type is tried? Also, what OS and browser?

Comment: Though, looking at the code, the problem appears to be at the imgur end :(

Comment: @Oded yes, it's working if you save the image and upload it from your computer. I think there is some redirect on drupal.org server.

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd - That would certainly cause problems.

Comment: @Oded nailed it. drupal.org are blocking remote requests to their files, trying to download the image with simple `DownloadData()` of the WebClient class resulted in "The remote server returned an error: (403) Forbidden"

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd - thanks for investigating. Why not post an answer?

Comment: @Oded good idea, done.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From some quick investigation it appears that drupal.org are blocking remote requests to their files.

Trying to download the image using code (simple DownloadData() of the WebClient class in C#) resulted in:

> The remote server returned an error: (403) Forbidden

This means that imgur code can't get images from drupal.org, it's not Stack Exchange fault or imgur fault.

Either ask drupal.org to remove the block, or host images elsewhere. :)

One thing though, it would be better to  change the error message from "format is not supported" to something like "failed to fetch remote image, error [number here]" which will make it more clear why it failed.

Comment: I can [confirm this in PHP](http://i.stack.imgur.com/A2ZPs.png). The fact that it reads `You should know better` indicates that it is very much intentional.

Comment: Oh! It must be a recent change, then, since I didn't have that problem before. I didn't think of that since I can see the images from my computer. Thinking better, it seems obvious why: I am watching the image clicking on a link from that site. `:)` Yes, the error message is confusing, since I thought the image was not returned with the correct content type.

Comment: @Antony looks like "you should know better" coming from PHP, don't see it with my C# code.

Comment: @kiamlaluno yeah, they expect a valid user agent. Probably it's possible to fool them by passing dummy browser details, but don't think it's a good idea. :)

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd I have checked. This message comes from drupal.org, not PHP.

Comment: @Antony OK, probably I didn't look deep enough. Cheers!

Comment: <insert obligatory Inception joke here>